# mysqldb python unknown database

Tags: python, database, mysql-python

I am trying to connect to MySQL using python 2.7. My code goes as follows

```
DB_HOST = '127.0.0.1' #'localhost'
DB_USER = 'root'
DB_PASSWORD = 'password'
DB_SCHEMA = 'database_one'
DB_TBL_PREFIX = 'database_'

import MySQLdB

db = MySQLdb.connect(host=DB_HOST, user=DB_USER, passwd=DB_PASSWORD, db='$$$$')
```

Inside my server (localhost) I have my database `(DB_SCHEMA)` and inside this database I have some tables `(DB_TBL_PREFIX.'table_name')`. If I want to choose one of this tables inside the database, what will it be the correct value of $$$$ ?. I have no problem using php but this python is driving me crazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you've written `$$$$`, you'll want `DB_SCHEMA`:

```
db = MySQLdb.connect(host=DB_HOST, user=DB_USER, passwd=DB_PASSWORD, db=DB_SCHEMA)
```

After that, you'll probably find http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_database_access.htm helpful to teach you the correct syntax.

In the long run, though, I'd suggest using an already-existing library like the excellent [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) rather than creating your SQL statements by hand. It's a rather different way of looking at things, especially if you're coming from a PHP background, but you wouldn't believe how much grief it will save you in the long run. Coding SQL by hand will force you to worry about SQL injection, properly escaping parameters, and all kinds of related issues, but when you use a library like SQLAlchemy all that will be done for you -- and tons more that you probably can't even imagine right now.

Seriously, investing time into learning to use SQLAlchemy will be time well spent.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how do i choose the right table inside the database?

Comment: You don't need to choose a table when you create the connection. You connect to the database with `db.connect(your_parameters)`, then create a cursor with `db.cursor()`, then run SQL statements on the cursor. It's all in the link I posted: search for "READ Operation".